# How to get single key and multiple value from dictionary of type d<int, list<T>>?

Tags: c#, collections

I am working on one scenerio where key and single value either min or max is selected from dict of type dict<int, list>.

Code snippet is below

```
Dict<int,int> selectedids = dicttoselect
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.key, x.value.Min(i=>i.id));
```

But in my case **I have two ids available against 1 key and I want select both ids get store in selectedids dictionary**.

For example
Key A ---> 1 as value
---> 2 as value

And I want both values of that key.

Please suggest solution to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use value tuples introduced in C# 7.0, where a tuple `(int min, int max)` stores both values

```cs
Dict<int,(int min, int max)> selectedids = dicttoselect
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.key,
        x => (x.value.Min(i=>i.id), x.value.Max(i=>i.id))
    );
```

You can then get an entry with

```cs
if (selectedids.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"min = {value.min}, max = {value.max}");
}
```

or

```cs
var (min, max) = selectedids[key];
Console.WriteLine($"min = {min}, max = {max}");
```

See also: [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

Answer (score 0):

> For example Key A ---> 1 as value ---> 2 as value

You already have them, because your dictionary maps a single int `keyA` to a list of ints:

```
dicttoselect[keyA]
```

This is a List of your two IDs. You use it anywhere you'd use a List:

```
foreach(var id in dicttoselect[keyA]) 
  Console.WriteLine("Key A has value " + id);
```

It will print 2 lines:

```
Key A has value 1
Key A has value 2
```

You can't store these two values (1 and 2) in a `Dictionary<int,int>`; the mapping of key:value in a dictionary is 1:1; the only thing you can do is what you have already done: have a single key `int` that maps to a single `List<int>` as the value, and then stash multiple ints inside the one List

---

Let's say you have some big Dictionary of all your stuff:

```
d[1] = { 2, 17, 22}
d[2] = { 3, 9, 55, 78}
d[3] = { 1, 40 }
```

And the user is using some UI where they have ticked key 1 and key 3; you want a list of all IDs they related to:

```
var userTicked = new[] {1, 3};

var r = userTicked.SelectMany(ut => d[ut]);
```

This will produce a single list of all IDs that relate to these choices:

```
2
17
22
1
40
```

This is what I *guess* you're looking for, because you will do something with those IDs. If you wanted the ID the user ticked with it too:

```
var r = userTicked.SelectMany(
  ut => d[ut], 
  (ut, listItem) => new { UserTicked = ut, ID = listItem }
);
```

And you'd get:

```
UserTicked, ID
1, 2
1, 17
1, 22
3, 1
3, 40
```

but you cannot store this in a Dictionary because of the duplicate keys; you'd have to use it as-is

---

If you're literally looking for using what the user ticked to be used in some lookup of N number objects then you could do like the following. Let's say that the IDs are for Cars:

```
//cars where the car id is in one of the lists the user ticked
listOfCars.Where(c => userTicked.Any(ut => d[ut].Contains(c.Id)));
```

That's probably a lot more confusing than the alternative though:

```
//convert user ticked lists into a single hashset
var wantedCarIDs = userTicked.SelectMany(ut => d[ut]).ToHashSet();

//then get all cars where their ID is in the hashset
listOfCars.Where(c => wantedCarIDs.Contains(c.Id));
```

Comment: dicttiselect have 50-60 records and one key 2 values types keys are also there. So need those all values of one key to be stored in selectedids dictionary against that key.

Comment: Currently I am getting key value pair in selectedids, but for key i am getting only min value and max value is filtered. I need both value against that key in selectedids  dictionary. Not required min and Max .

Comment: *So need those all values of one key to be stored in selectedids dictionary against that key*. It cannot be done. See the last paragraph of the answer. You cannot take a `Dictionary<int,int[]>` that is mapping `d[99] => { 1, 2 }` and store both values into a `Dictionary<int,int>`  like `d[99] = 1; d[99] = 2;` and have it remember both. It's like asking "how do I get an `int` to store two ints"? It can't be done. You cannot say `int x = 100; x = 200;` and expect x to also remember the 100

Comment: You could use a Lookup, but that's only effectively the same as what you already have.. A `Lookup<int,int>` is notionally the same thing as a `Dictionary<int,List<int>>`

Comment: Yes correct, that why I was stuck with this scenerio and need effective solution on this because that selectedids is used in condition as well in later code. I can get all values by doing dicttiselect.select(x=>x.value) and then in list<int> ilist = selectedids.select(x=>x.id).tointlist();